# Windows Azure Subdomain Re-Routing with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following issue, lets say I create an A record with my domain like *.mydomain.com, my main domain has a CNAME record pointing to my Windows Azure given domain name.  So it goes as follows:

A record: *.mydomain.com 127.0.0.1
CNAME record: mydomain.com myservice.cloudapp.net

Now I want the ability to control custom subdomain in my application, so the user for example can create their own subdomain.  This subdomain will obviously not really exist, but I will be capturing and handling the routing on my own using ASP.NET MVC.  I have seen this done using .htcaccess, but I have not seen it done using ASP.NET MVC or Windows Azure...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible - there is an excellent [blog](http://lukesampson.com/post/303245177/subdomains-for-a-single-application-with-asp-net-mvc) entry on this issue.

Comment: I am hoping adding Windows Azure into the picture does not complicate this solution, I guess I won't know until I try it out.

Thanks!